# SF1 - get hamburger button to display instead of back button

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile

I'm running through a workflow and then end it with navigating the user to a record's page (an account, for example) yet the back button displays instead of the hamburger menu. So, if a user wants to get back to the "home" page they have to navigate press the back arrow the way through the workflow they just went through.

I can't find anything on this...is it possible or a salesforce limitation?

Another possible workaround is sending the user back to their home screen but I have no idea how to do that either and can't find anything online for that.

Comment: It sounds like this is a visual flow, is that correct? Are you presenting it in a lightning component or visualforce page?

Comment: @Kyle several vf pages in a row